# Pattern attribute not working as expected?

Tags: html

So I'm trying to make a form for my assignment, and I am using the pattern attribute in html so only certain characters are required to be typed on the text box. But for some reason, the form is saying using that I'm using an incorrect format even though I made my pattern attribute that way.

Here's an example of the code and a picture of the problem.

```html
<form>
  <label for="mnumber">Mobile Number:</label>
  <input type="text" required id="mnumber" pattern="[0-9]"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: When adding screenshots, please make sure to only screenshot relevant parts of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You did write:

`pattern="[0-9]"`

You are asking for only one number. You just forget to add '+' to accept more than one number. I guess what you are searching for is this:

`pattern="[0-9]+"`

Answer (score 3):

```
pattern="[0-9]"
```

allows for only a **single** number character to validate (and be submitted). If you want to allow more than one character, here's your options:

- One or more numbers:

  ```
  pattern="[0-9]+"
  ```
- Zero or more numbers:

  ```
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  ```
- One to three numbers:

  ```
  pattern="[0-9]{1,3}"
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much, my issue has been resolved and those will be very helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change type="text" to **type="number"**

Comment: This question specifically is about the `pattern` attribute. Also `input type="number"` allows entering alot of characters the pattern would disallow, like `.`, scientific notation, `+`, `-`.